# Slow fluctuating internet in Ubuntu but faster in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in my computer. For some unknown weird reason, the speed of internet is very slow with heavy fluctuations in my machine. But I have Windows 7 running on the virtual box which is really smooth and super fast. I'm using the LAN cable and not on wifi. Also, on the other devices, the internet is working properly.

I tried some possible things like connecting the system to a different LAN port, changing the switch etc., and I couldn't find any improvement. So, I strongly believe that, there should be some problem with the system only. Friends, please help me come out of this issue.

[history.log](http://textuploader.com/5g63z)

[dpkg.log](http://txt.do/5g6i0)

This doesn't show much difference, totally strange :(

Please help guys.

**Edit:** I tried to boot from USB. But it doesn't work there as well. So, completely out of idea.